# How to accelerate Reading/Writing Attribute Data?

Tags: linux, module, filesystems

I used File attributes in the sys filesystem which allow userspace to communicate with the driver using SysFS. The problem is that I have much data to be transfered so I lost much time. This is a very slow process!

In the kennel module I have this part of the code:

```
static DEVICE_ATTR(writeFile,S_IWUSR,NULL,writeFunction);

static DEVICE_ATTR(resultFile,S_IRUSR, readFunction, NULL);

    static ssize_t writeFunction(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
     const char * buf, size_t count) {

    if(count >0){
    resp_ready = 1;

    sscanf(buf,"%2x,",&src_vect[0]);
    for (i=0;i<80;i++)
             {
                sscanf(buf+3+12*i,"%2x,%2x,%2x,%2x,",&src_vect[4*i+1],&src_vect[4*i+2],&src_vect[4*i+3],&src_vect[4*i+4]);

             }
    .
    .
    .
        }

static ssize_t readFunction(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf) {

//write the result to buf   
       for (i=0;i<6;i++)
          {  
            sprintf(buf+72*i,"%8x,%8x,%8x,%8x,%8x,%8x,%8x,%8x,",dst_f[8*i],dst_f[8*i+1],dst_f[8*i+2],dst_f[8*i+3],dst_f[8*i+4],dst_f[8*i+5],dst_f[8*i+6],dst_f[8*i+7]);

          }
.
.
.
}
```

How can I reduce data transfer time from/to user/kennel space?
Is there any method faster than this one?

Comment: Any suggestion or help please

Comment: sprintf/sscanf are fairly slow. Change it to read/write binary data.  You are using "%x" at least, much faster than "%d", but still, much slower than doing  no conversion at all.